# xp_sendmail: failed with mail error 0x80004005

Tags: sql-server-2000

when I run xp_sendmail

```
exec master.dbo.xp_sendmail @recipients='me@hotmail.com', 
@subject='terrrible thing happened',  
@message='test'`
```

I am getting an error

> Msg 18025, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   xp_sendmail: failed with mail error 0x80004005

It is SQL Server 2000. Outlook is set on this box. I can send emails from the Outlook.
It worked before. We just moved the server to DMZ.

We disabled Trendmicro antivirus's firewall

Comment: Has this ever worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysadmin opened some ports and that fixed an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you logged into the server with the account which the SQL service is running under, and configured outlook under that account?

Comment: Yes, I logged in as SQL Server account. Outlook works fine, I can email. SSMS>SupportServices>SQLMail>Properties>TestEmail works "sucessfully started and stopped a MAPI session with this profile"

Comment: Sysadmin opened some ports and that fixed an issue.